# How to connect Google Account to Yahoo Account?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management, yahoo-mail

So I have this name@ymail.com account at Yahoo and I also have a name@gmail.com account.

I want to log into Yahoo Mail with the Gmail account using OpenID. However, the only option available in Yahoo Mail is to disconnect other login accounts. How do I even connect in the first place?

If I log in to Yahoo with name@gmail.com, I have the option of creating a new Yahoo Account with either a @yahoo.com or @yahoo.ca domain. But I want to connect an existing Yahoo Account and with the @ymail.com domain instead.

Comment: If above solution not works try this solution....


http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37199/30388

Answer (score 1):

I shall not say anything, just refer to the screenshots below and make your way through:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Click on **Sign in to Connect**

[image]

Comment: That doesn't help connect existing accounts.

Comment: It does, I have tried it and connected my accounts.

Comment: _"I shall not say anything, just refer to the screenshots below and make your way through:"_ That's not very helpful to people with vision impairments.