# Log in to Yahoo! Mail using Google account or adding existing Yahoo ID to Google account

Tags: google-account, account-management, yahoo-mail

I want to use my Google account to log in to  Yahoo account or email ID.

So I want to link my Google account to the existing Yahoo account.

I read the answer at this link: [How to connect Google Account to Yahoo Account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/how-to-connect-google-account-to-yahoo-account/26267#26267)

but when i reached step 2 (screen shot 2) and enter the gmail account credentials it log me to yahoo.com as m********n@gmail.com but not linked(or login) to my existing yahoo account .

So how to link the gmail id to the yahoo account or yahoo email id?

Comment: i solved problem

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so it can benefit other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the solution First read the  reason of the problem:

Following the solution on [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/how-to-connect-google-account-to-yahoo-account/26267#26267)

I have entered my name and date of birth in step3 (screen shot no.3),after entering gmail credentials in step2(screen shot 2), instead of clicking on “sign in to connect”(screen shot 3)  I clicked on 'Continue'

*so yahoo make the new yahoo account as m**********n@gmail.com instead of linking the gmail id to yahoo id.*

Thus who do such mistake not got linked their gmail id to yahoo id.

So first we need to delete the yahoo account created with gmail id and then go to link gmail id to existing yahoo id for login purpose.

**Here is the solution**:

1. First login using your Gmail ID or Facebook ID you want to add to Yahoo ID
2. Go to the home page and click over your name it will open the Yahoo profile
3. Now click on your name on top left on Yahoo profile page, their you found option account info
4. Click on the account info and it will ask again for password, enter the password again and open account info page
5. On account info page look for **Manage other accounts to sign into**
6. Click on this option and you will find your Gmail ID here and in front of it you see the remove option, now click on remove option
7. This will close the your account associated to Gmail ID

Now follow the procedure on [this link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/how-to-connect-google-account-to-yahoo-account/26267#26267) and you will be able to connect your Gmail ID to Yahoo ID.